# Batch - Create Folders with one changing variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

So I want to create lots of different folders (lots!) which will have the following format:

```
RobocopyVAR          -  where VAR will be a letter, or number etc.
```

Just for learning purposes, how could I create a basic batch file to automate creating folders:

```
RobocopyA       through to           RobocopyZ
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this into a batch file:

```
for %%L in (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z) DO (md Robocopy%%L)
```

Comment: Similar. You basically just need `start` and `end`

Comment: Ah sorry, I read **bash** not **batch**. Let me correct my response

Comment: Corrected it. Place the code into a file e.g. makeDir.bat and run it.